# android picker rotation speed

Tags: android, view, numberpicker

I'm using a NumberPicker for letting the user selection custom string values.
Works quite well, except the wheel is too sensitive, too fast, to select a value easily.
Is there a way to adjust the rotation velocity, acceleration of Android Pickers?
Thanks!